# Can't copy/paste because of ending some processes

Tags: windows-xp, copy-paste

I accidently ended some processes in Task Manager (some svchost.exe I guess), now I can't copy/paste. How to fix it?

Windows XP SP3

Comment: Have you tried rebooting already?

Comment: haha my noob question, sorry, just restart it. xD

Comment: It's just the number-one answer to any Windows problem ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reboot your computer.

(Killing a task does not permanently disable it - like after a reboot).

Comment: I have just restarted, it works!

Comment: Of course this will work, even our secretary would be able to figure this out. Fixing everything by restart is not a solution. This way I would keep restarting all day long.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem. Couldn't copy paste from the notepad/R to notepad/R. I tried to follow [this advice](http://forums.whatthetech.com/index.php?showtopic=125518) but I couldn't clear the clipboard and needed to kill clipbrd in the Task Manager. It didn't help. What *did* finally help was to **copy some text from Firefox and paste it to Notepad**. This seems to have fixed the problem!